# Post on Pyimagesearch blog

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning

I can't figure out how to post a question on the pyimagesearch.com blogs.  There are a number of topics, each of which has a trail of postings and responses, but I cannot see how to post a question to the topic.  The site does not have an open forum.  That is why I am asking here.

Thanks

Comment: you need to pay for it

Comment: In the comments section: _I’d be happy to help you with your question or project, but I have to politely ask you to purchase one of my books or courses first._

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it simply has no business here.

Answer (score 0):

they did respond that the questions are submitted to one email address. It appears that they put the questions and responses on different articles.  There is no way to post directly.